# Start QT UI from Pycharm

Tags: qt, pycharm, qt-designer

My problem is that i installed QT Designer and also implemented QT as an external tool in my Pycharm. This means I can open QT by pressing Tools --> External Tools --> QTdesigner. I created a little test UI and safed it in my Projectdirectory. Now I convert this .ui file with pyside2-uic.exe. I posted this as a picture.

[image: Picture of external tool]

Now i can rightclick on my .ui file in my Project and choose under External Tools the PyUIC. It builds a .py file. So far so good. Here is my problem. Now I press run but nothing happens. I can´t start the UI from here. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try add `-x` in arguments

Comment: At which point?